# How to implement didTapCheckBox of BEMCheckBox IOS Library?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in Ios and i am having hard time wrapping my head around protocols and delegates concept. I am implementing a library called BEMCheckBox https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMCheckBox or https://cocoapods.org/pods/BEMCheckBox for implementing radio buttons. Its documentation is pretty descriptive using which i have successfully added checkboxes, grouped them together to work as radio boxes.

```
@IBOutlet var inarelashipcb: BEMCheckBox!
@IBOutlet var complicatedcb: BEMCheckBox!
@IBOutlet var singlecb: BEMCheckBox!
var groupbx:BEMCheckBoxGroup!

func initialize(){
  groupbx = BEMCheckBoxGroup(checkBoxes: [inarelashipcb, 
 complicatedcb, singlecb])
    groupbx.selectedCheckBox = singlecb
    groupbx.mustHaveSelection = true
 }
```

Now i want to use didTapCheckBox method but i donot understand how. The documentation is blurry there no snippets for that. For the record this is what the documentation states

"BEMCheckBox uses a delegate to receive check box events. The delegate object must conform to the BEMCheckBoxDelegate protocol, which is composed of two optional methods:

didTapCheckBox:
Sent to the delegate every time the check box gets tapped, after its properties are updated (on), but before the animations are completed."

Any snippets to help me use delgate so i can implement didTapCheckBox method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outlet checkbox you have declared, set delegate to self.
For eg, if your checkbox outlet is checkbox1 set its delegate as 
checkbox1.delegate = self

Answer (score 3):

```
func initialize(){
  groupbx = BEMCheckBoxGroup(checkBoxes: [inarelashipcb, 
 complicatedcb, singlecb])
    groupbx.selectedCheckBox = singlecb
    groupbx.mustHaveSelection = true
    for checkbox in groupbx {
      checkbox.delegate = self
    }

 }
```

must call `initialize` in `viewDidLoad` of the viewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    // Do your work
     initialize()
}
```

compiler will show you an error, error will be gone if you add this codes

```
extension ViewController : BEMCheckBoxDelegate {
     func didTap(_ checkBox: BEMCheckBox) {
        //do your work 
        // if you have multiple checkboxes, then do like that 
        //if checkBox == checkBox1 {
           //do work for checkbox1 
        //} else if {
        // ..
        //}
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the following line

`import BEMCheckBox`

Comment: Implementing your code i am getting compile time error :                                          Value of type 'BEMCheckBoxGroup?' has no member 'delegate'

Comment: Its on this instruction "groupbx.delegate = self"

Comment: YES, BEMCheckBoxGroup has no member delegate, delegate is for single checkbox, you have to add delegate method iterating a loop, I have updated , let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
I solve it.

using this code 

func initialize(){
  groupbx = BEMCheckBoxGroup(checkBoxes: [inarelashipcb, 
 complicatedcb, singlecb])
    groupbx.selectedCheckBox = singlecb
    groupbx.mustHaveSelection = true
  inarelashipcb.delegate =  self
        complicatedcb.delegate = self
        singlecb.delegate = self
 }


       func didTap(_ checkBox: BEMCheckBox) {
    print("here hello")
}
```

Also my uiviewcontroller inherited from BEMCheckBoxDelegate